# Netbeans 8.2 Home page1

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

I have kali linux 2018.03. I can't create (java) project in Netbeans 8.2. It doesn't give me an error or something like that, just the home page.

I have the latest version of java, but I can't create new project or new file.

Comment: Are you sure that your Netbeans installation is working ? did you try to create a different project using Netbeans ?

Comment: _"I have the latest version of java"_ => That's your problem. The most recent version of Java supported by NetBeans 8.2 is Java 8. Java versions 9, 10 and 11 just won't work with NetBeans 8.2.